# How to copy all files in same directory as gulpfile?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

My gulpfile.js is in the same folder as the project folder. I'm trying to copy all the folders and files over to `dist/`:

```
// copy all files in current dir
gulp.src("./**/*", {base: "./"})
   .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
```

But this doesn't copy anything over. Why?

Comment: I had a similar problem. I ended up not using `base`, and using `__dirname` with the glob instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
gulp.task('build', function(){
    gulp.src( ["./**/*"], {base: "./"} ).pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```